# My angular script only works when I open my html page as a static file and not when I run it with django

Tags: angularjs, django, html

I've got an array inside my `<script>` tags and am trying to reference it in the html body:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('HomeController', function($scope){
        this.posts = feedback;
    });

    app.controller('TabController', function($scope){
        this.tab = 1;

        this.setTab = function(newValue){
            this.tab = newValue;
        };

        this.isSet = function(tabName){
            return this.tab === tabName;
        };
    });

    var feedback = [{
        author: 'Joe Shmo',
        body: 'I really love this product, no complaints',
        votes: 0,
        createdOn: 1397490980837,
        tags: ['great', 'cool'],
        people: ['Santa Clause']
    },
    {
        author: 'Stinky Pete',
        body: 'Sucky product all around',
        votes: 0,
        createdOn: 1397490980837,
        tags: ['terrible', 'stinks'],
        people: ['Tooth Fairy']
    }];
</script>
</head>
<body>
<section ng-controller="TabController as tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(1) }">
            <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(2) }">
            <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Groups</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(3) }">
            <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Notifications</a>
        </li>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)" ng-controller="HomeController as home">
            <h3>Home Base</h3>
            <div ng-repeat="post in home.posts">
                <h4>{{ post.author }} <em class="pull-right">{{ post.votes }}</em></h4>
                <h5>{{ post.createdOn | date }}</h5>
                <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
            <h3>Your Groups</h3>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
            <h3>Nothing to see here.</h3>
        </div>
    </ul>
</section>
</body>
```

When I have this running in the browser, I don't get any errors, but when I click the "Home" tab, only Home Base appears and, upon inspecting the page, the `<h4>, <h5>` and `<p>` tags are all there, but they are empty.  Any help would be appreciated!

FOLLOW UP: I'm using Angular1.4.9, Django1.9 with REST framework, could it be some kind of compatibility issue?

As many of the comments have said, the content is displayed when you open it as a static file, but when I have my django server going, the content does not appear.

Comment: Works http://jsbin.com/vapiqocuvo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Suggest reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: worked for me... https://plnkr.co/edit/LAsk1BKNbMPljzeLLUGr?p=preview

Comment: I don't understand how it is working for everyone else, I'm still not able to see any of the info between {{ }} on my web page.  Could it be a deeper issue with Django or the REST framework I'm using?  @ClydeLobo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with Django and Angular.  Both use the {{ }} notation so the interpreter was seeing `{{ post.author }}` as django and not angular.  The way to fix this was to put `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}` at the beginning and end of my html file, and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by doing two things:

1. Using $scope for the "posts" var:

Replace this:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope){
    this.posts = feedback;
});
```

With This:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope){
  $scope.posts = feedback;
});
```

Next - Remove "home" from the ng-repeat here:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController as home">
  <h3>Home Base</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h4>{{ post.author }} 
    <em class="pull-right">{{ post.votes }}    </em></h4>
    <h5>{{ post.createdOn | date }}</h5>
    <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code in question works as well. Your code doesn't use controller as syntax

Comment: I tried this but got the same result with empty <h4> <h5> and <p> tags

Comment: Do I need to add $scope to my feedback array as well?

Comment: You don't need $scope for feedback array because it doesn't reside inside of controller (which is the only reason that $scope exists) - it is really just a global variable you declared on your root page (not the best idea, but I didn't want to convolute the answer.) 

I would really consider making it super simple.. Make $scope.post equal the actual array (rather than use a global variable for it) - remove all HIDE/SHOWS - see if that works... gradually add all your other logic in until every works or you find out what isn't. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you may be using angular version 1.1.4 or below. Your code works if angular is v 1.1.5  or above. This is because Controller as syntax  used in your code was introduced post 1.1.5

None working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/
This gives below error. Check your console.

```
Error: Argument 'TabController as tab' is not a function, got undefined
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/683/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('HomeController', function($scope){
        this.posts = feedback;
    });

    app.controller('TabController', function($scope){
        this.tab = 1;

        this.setTab = function(newValue){
            this.tab = newValue;
        };

        this.isSet = function(tabName){
            return this.tab === tabName;
        };
    });

    var feedback = [{
        author: 'Joe Shmo',
        body: 'I really love this product, no complaints',
        votes: 0,
        createdOn: 1397490980837,
        tags: ['great', 'cool'],
        people: ['Santa Clause']
    },
    {
        author: 'Stinky Pete',
        body: 'Sucky product all around',
        votes: 0,
        createdOn: 1397490980837,
        tags: ['terrible', 'stinks'],
        people: ['Tooth Fairy']
    }];
```

Comment: I'm using angular1.4.9 so I don't think that's it, thanks though

Comment: No errors, the tabs function properly, it's just that the information under the tabs won't show up.  I wish I could post a screenshot of what it looks like in my browser.